# Display an array of string in custom format

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I have an array of name like this

```
let arrayOfName = ["alex","lonzo","lavar"]
```

and sometimes my array only has 1 element but it will never be empty

```
let arrayOfName = ["lavar"]
```

is there a way that I can display all the names in this string format?
For example in the 1st case:

```
"studentName=alex&studentName=lonzo&studentName=lavar"
```

and for the 2nd case, it would be

```
"studentName=lavar"
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: FYI - If you are doing this to build a URL with a query string then please look into `URLComponents` and `URLQueryItem`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a map and joined:

```
let arrayOfName = ["alex","lonzo","lavar"]
let namesResult = arrayOfName.map { "studentName=\($0)" }.joined(separator: "&")
print(namesResult)
```

Result:

> studentName=alex&studentName=lonzo&studentName=lavar

This will work even if the array has zero or one name or any number of names.